Is the following Inverse Computational co-Diffie-Hellman problem hard?
Let $\langle g \rangle \stackrel{\Delta}{=} \mathbb{G}$ and $\langle h \rangle \stackrel{\Delta}{=} \mathbb{H}$ be groups of prime order $p$. Given $( p, g, g^\delta, g^{\delta^{-1}}, h, h^\delta )$, compute $h^{\delta^{-1}}$.
I have not seen this problem in literature, and was wondering if it does in fact hold (or not).
I can see that if $\mathbb{G}$ and $\mathbb{H}$ are pairing-friendly, then clearly the decisional version is easy, but the above problem seems plausibly hard. That said, I don't know what assumption one could reduce its hardness to (in the plain model).

How are $\mathbb{G}$ and $\mathbb{H}$ related?  Can we assume that $g$ and $h$ are the same order $p$?

Yes, $p$ is the common group order. I made an update to be more precise.

What can we assume about the groups? Or is the question whether this problem potentially reduces to something else?

In the 'abstract group' model, I believe you can prove it hard (assuming the groups are large enough); however that's not very likely to be the answer you're looking for...

Yes, I can actually prove it in the algebraic group model from hardness of discrete log. I can't figure out a plain model proof.
